# Perfect distro for small office web server + version control server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, git, svn, webserver

I'm willing to put one of my old "pentium" machine as a local web server at my small office. And willing to install a version control server SVN or GIT (I'm new to version controlling) on it.

I'm preferring to use Ubuntu as the platform for this server and my thought is to install Ubuntu-server (12.10 or 12.04) distribution. 
However I'm not sure with the Ubuntu-server distro provides any support for SVN or GIT. I mean can I use these version control servers without a gui?

Comment: Are you sure you want to trust your source code repositories to an *old* machine?

Comment: Any Linux distribution is fine for almost anything—it honestly does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

Git is a *distributed* version control system. It doesn't require a central server. But you can use git on the server and e.g. push repositories to it from your development machine.

Both git and subversion should work on basically all UNIX-like operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu server is fine. The differences with the desktop edition are in the kernel (different options but same sources) and missing gui.

Version: use 13.04 - the *.04 are LTS (long term support) so will be viable for much more time than the other releases.

Version control:

- GIT is distributed and you can't say there is central server althouh usually there is a central place to put releases/branches determined to be usefull. Look into gitolite. It will save you much much time.
- SVN has a daemon called svnserve and there are quite some guides how to use and abuse it so shouldn't be an issue. For SVN i highly recommend Trac (as it provides also project management, ticketing, releases, wiki and other goodies).

Having no gui is not a problem, just a small challenge to motivate you to learn a bit for the command line.

Comment: And still allows for web-based UIs like webmin for administration

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, ubuntu-server is the same ubuntu, just with different kernel 
and for sure you can get all the software which is available from ubuntu repositories, not matter whether it is server or desktop oriented.